# How can I generate a two-dimensional array list with a two-dimensional index?

Tags: list, shapes

I'm using image data whose shape is (512,512). From my data, I'm trying to use data whose value is positive. Therefore, I got an index for the corresponding data. However, when I try to use the chosen data, since the shape of data changes, I can't draw the image...

My code was like this.

```
data1 = D1.data
data1 = data1[0,0,...]  # -> (512,512)
data1_inx = np.where(data1 > 0)

for i in range(len(data1_inx[:1])):
    for j in range(len(data1_inx[1:])):
        data1 = data1[data1_inx[i][j]]
print(data1.shape)  # -> (512,)
```

How can I generate a two-dimensional array with a two-dimensional index?

Comment: Using what? [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# Assuming you have the image data stored in 'data1'
data1 = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=(512, 512))  # Example data

# Generate 2D array with positive values
data1_indices = np.where(data1 > 0)
data1_positive = np.zeros_like(data1)

for i, j in zip(data1_indices[0], data1_indices[1]):
    data1_positive[i, j] = data1[i, j]

print(data1_positive.shape)  # (512, 512)
```

This code extracts positive values from a randomly generated 2D array and stores them in a new array, setting all other elements to zero.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76712592/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Is it okayyyy ?

Answer (score -1):

To generate a 2D array list with 2D indices in Python, you can use nested loops. Start by defining the number of rows and columns for the array. Then, create an empty 2D array list using a list comprehension that includes the row and column indices. This will result in a 2D array where each element is identified by its row and column index. The example provided creates a 5x5 2D array with elements initialized to zero[,](https://zedlouder.com/category/gospel/) but you can adjust the dimensions and initial values based on your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Smart Nzowa!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Re *"The example provided creates a 5x5 2D array"*: What example? Example code generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (not copy-pasted here)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).